# How to set up a two-way Git mirror?

Tags: git

The Microsoft .NET Core CLR GitHub repo:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr

It mentions on that page that it does two-way Git mirroring between internal Microsoft servers and GitHub.  I'd like to set up something similar with Gogs on my internal network and GitHub for the public-facing side.

What series of commands is being used to implement their two-way Git mirror?

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach to mirroring Git repositories is to implement a `post-receive` hook which pushes the new refs to the mirror repo.  Things on Github will be a little trickier, because you don't have direct access to the hooks there -- instead, you'll need to use a Github "webhook" to notify an external service that the push has taken place, and cause a pull/push to happen from the Github repo to the internally-maintained one.

Frankly, though, mirroring -- *especially* bidirectional mirroring -- is almost always a sign of organisational dysfunction.  Answer the question, "why shouldn't everyone just push directly to Github?" (or "directly to Gogs?") to determine what you need to fix, which will make the mirroring unnecessary.